# Running mulitple process in Node JS

Tags: node.js

Okay so I'm trying to build a web service for twitter automation. I have build bots before that works only for a single account.

The service that I'm looking to build will enable users to register and then set up some preference (like follow users that tweets #ILoveProgramming).

**My main question is** - right now if I need to run the bot I just type "*node bot.js*" and the bot will run. How do I run multiple process for all the hundred users that'll be using my Web Service ?

Comment: can you provide some code ?

Comment: You want to launch a new process for each users ?

Comment: @TGrif I am not aware of any other ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJs provides clustering module which would spin up multiple process of your program.

It basically involves creating a master and workers processes.
The docs for it are available [here](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

Also I would suggest using process managers like [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2), which provide support for clustering and manage them very well. You could read about it [here](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/).

With pm2, doing something like

```
pm2 start bot.js -i max
```

would start the bot server for all the cpu's/cores in your device.

Comment: While pm2 does help running multiple process at once I however want to make everything dynamic. Once a user registers, a new process should be initiated automatically

Comment: Then you should use the cluster module from Nodejs.
It provides abilities to create worker process

Answer (score 0):

Running a process for every user will not be a scalable way to achieve this. You can try using [async.each](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each) to run the same function for every user in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify cluster information in pm2 configuration file like this,

File: process.yml

`apps:
  - script   : <your script name>
    name     : <name of your app>
    instances: <number of instances you want to run>
    exec_mode: cluster`

and then start pm2 like this,
`pm2 start process.yml`